# How to test methods with similar arguments in Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm writing a Junit test using Mockito that accepts the same arguments, but with different sub-arguments in one of those arguments. For example:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public class SampleMockito {

    @Mock
    private Widget widget;

    private static Machine machine;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
    machine = new Machine();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    Mockito.when(widget.doAction(Mockito.eq("Setting 1"), Mockito.any(Values.class))).thenReturn("Action 1 done.");
    Mockito.when(widget.doAction(Mockito.eq("Setting 1"), Mockito.any(Values.class))).thenReturn("Action 2 done.");
    Mockito.when(widget.doAction(Mockito.eq("Setting 2"), Mockito.any(Values.class))).thenReturn("Action 3 done.");
    Mockito.when(widget.doAction(Mockito.eq("Setting 2"), Mockito.any(Values.class))).thenReturn("Action 4 done.");

    }

    @Test
    public void testPerformAction() {
    // Some sample test code that I have not written.
    }
}
```

Here's my POJO

```
public class Widget {

    public String doAction(String param, Values values) {
    System.out.println("Do Some Irrelevant Action");
    return null;
    }
}
```

And the worker class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Machine {

    public boolean performAction(Widget w, Document doc) {
    // Action 1
    w.doAction("Setting 1", new Values("Argument 1", "Argument 2"));
    // Action 2
    w.doAction("Setting 1", new Values("Argument 1a", new Exception("Exception message.")));
    // Action 3
    w.doAction("Setting 2", new Values("Argument 1", "Argument 2"));
    // Action 4
    w.doAction("Setting 2", new Values("Argument 1a", new Exception("Exception message.")));

    return false;
    }
}

class Values extends ArrayList<Object> {
    public Values() {

    }

    public Values(Object... vals) {
    super(vals.length);
    for (Object o : vals) {
        add(o);
    }
    }
}
```

As they are defined currently, Mockito can't differentiate between actions 1 and 2, and actions 3 and 4. I would like to be able to tell Mockito that it should expect a certain number of Strings, or to expect an exception of some kind as arguments of the Values object. Is there a way to do this in Mockito? Or some other mock testing framework?

Comment: Don't use `any(Values.class)`. Use `argThat(...)`. Note that you should almost never, and certainly not in this case, extend ArrayList. Instead, **use** one.

Answer (score 0):

At the suggestion of @JB Nizet, I've changed my code to implement **argThat(...)**, removed the inheritence relationship between Values and ArrayList, and implemented [this](https://sites.google.com/a/pintailconsultingllc.com/java/argument-matching-with-mockito) to use **argThat()**:

```
package tinkering;

import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import tinkering.Machine.Values;

public class SampleMockito {

    @Mock
    private Widget widget;

    private static Machine machine;
    private List<Object> vals;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
    machine = new Machine();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Test
    public void testPerformAction() {
    machine.performAction(widget, new Document("dumb"));
    Mockito.verify(widget).doAction(Mockito.eq("Setting 1"), (Values) Mockito.argThat(new PerformActionArgumentStringArgsMatcher()));
    Mockito.verify(widget).doAction(Mockito.eq("Setting 1"), (Values) Mockito.argThat(new PerformActionArgumentMixedArgsMatcher()));
    Mockito.verify(widget).doAction(Mockito.eq("Setting 2"), (Values) Mockito.argThat(new PerformActionArgumentStringArgsMatcher()));
    Mockito.verify(widget).doAction(Mockito.eq("Setting 2"), (Values) Mockito.argThat(new PerformActionArgumentMixedArgsMatcher()));
    }

    class PerformActionArgumentStringArgsMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object arg) {
        if (arg instanceof Values) {
            vals = ((Values) arg).getList();
            if (vals.size() != 2)
                return false;
            if (!vals.get(0).equals("Argument 1"))
                return false;
            if (!vals.get(1).equals("Argument 2"))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    }

    class PerformActionArgumentMixedArgsMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object arg) {
        if (arg instanceof Values) {
            vals = ((Values) arg).getList();
            if (vals.size() != 2)
                return false;
            if (!vals.get(0).equals("Argument 1a"))
                return false;
            if (!(vals.get(1) instanceof Exception) && !((Exception) vals.get(1)).getMessage().equals("Exception message."))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    }

}
```

Changes to Machine.java:

```
package tinkering;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Machine {

    public boolean performAction(Widget w, Document doc) {
    // Action 1
    w.doAction("Setting 1", new Values("Argument 1", "Argument 2"));
    // Action 2
    w.doAction("Setting 1", new Values("Argument 1a", new Exception("Exception message.")));
    // Action 3
    w.doAction("Setting 2", new Values("Argument 1", "Argument 2"));
    // Action 4
    w.doAction("Setting 2", new Values("Argument 1a", new Exception("Exception message.")));

    return false;
    }

    class Values {
    private ArrayList<Object> list;

    public ArrayList<Object> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<Object> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public Values() {

    }

    public Values(Object... vals) {
        list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for (Object o : vals) {
            list.add(o);
        }
    }
}
```

Which compiles and successfully passes.